# Microsoft Teams SSO enabled Personal Tab -- 'Cannot access a disposed object. ObjectName: JSObjectReference'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

First, I'll describe the purpose of my Personal Tab and why I created it.
I needed an app that runs in background and makes Graph API calls on behalf of the user periodically. However the Graph API endpoint I need to call doesn't support any application permission, that's why I need the user to be logged in to make those calls. For that I created a Personal Tab app using Teams Toolkit in VS2022. It created a template blazor app with multiple components. I removed all the extra components and just use a single component that is displayed in my personal tab. It just has some welcome text. However, in the backend, in `OnAfterRenderAsync()` method, I used a `Timer` object which executes a method every 10 minutes. In that method, I create a `GraphServiceClient` using `teamsUserCredential` injected in the razor page using `@inject TeamsUserCredential teamsUserCredential` statement above. Then I make the API calls using this client and everything works fine. After about 90 minutes, the API call starts throwing exception `'Cannot access a disposed object. Object Name: JSObjectReference'`
I think this happens because the access token expires after approx. 90 minutes. I have added `offline_access` permission to my app registration and also granted admin consent for it. I think when the access token expires, the teamsUserCredential need to be updated and for that it needs to call some JS code that is the part of the webpage in the iframe on the personal tab. The exception is thrown because by that time the user has switched from the personal tab to somewhere else.
I need guidance that how can I achieve this, calling Graph API periodically on behalf of the user.

Comment: I think calling TeamsUserCredential will not work when you switch the Tab since it may fail to get SSO token. You need to handle the token yourself in your server code. I think it may be more suitable if you use a time trigger bot in your scenario.

Comment: Is there a way to get refresh token from this TeamsUserCredential and store it in a DB, then have another console app use that refresh token to obtain access token on behalf of the user and use that to call graph?

Comment: Using the `acquireTokenByRefreshToken` method of the `ConfidentialClientApplication` class in the msal library, you can pass the refresh token as a parameter to this method to obtain a new access token.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `AuthenticationProvider` class provided by the Microsoft Graph SDK, we can renew the access token before it expires. This class automatically handles token acquisition and renewal.

```
@inject ITokenProvider tokenProvider
@inject GraphServiceClient graphClient

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        // Get the access token
        var accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "User.Read" });
        // Set the access token in the GraphServiceClient
        graphClient.AuthenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
        // Make the API calls using the GraphServiceClient
        // ...
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

To handle the scenario where the user switches from the Personal Tab to another tab, you can use the `VisibilityState` API provided by the Teams JavaScript SDK. This API allows you to detect when the tab becomes visible or hidden. You can use it to stop or resume your periodic API calls.

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    microsoftTeams.registerOnVisibilityChangeHandler(function (visibility) {
        if (visibility === microsoftTeams.VisibilityState.visible) {
            // Resume your periodic API calls
        } else {
            // Stop your periodic API calls
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the thing is that I don't want to stop the API calls when the user switches tabs, or even if they logout. Basically I needed a daemon app and I want to call Graph on user's behalf periodically for a long period of time. Since there is no application permission for the graph endpoint I want to hit, the daemon approach doesn't work. That's why I created teams tab with SSO, so that the user once logs in to the tab, after that I don't want the user to come back to the tab, I just want to use this credential I retrieved for a long period of time in background.